# Piecewise function Syntax error only in debug mode

Tags: bugs, syntax, piecewise, debugging

If I enter the following through mathematica (11.0) through UI $$\begin{cases} 1 &x \geq 0 \\ 0 &True \end{cases}$$ No error is reported. 
 $$\begin{cases} 1 &x \geq 0 \\ 0 &True \end{cases} //InputForm$$ returns `Piecewise[{{1, x >= 0}}, 0]` However If I enter the same when the notebook is in debug mode it gives error

> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .

So as it seems some syntax is incorrect on debug mode, correct otherwise. Is the systax correct or wrong ?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem.  Can you report this to Wolfram Support?