# Using Dialog inside a function to debug

Tags: debugging

I need to understand why my functions doesn't work.

Thus, I have put a Dialog at the beginning of it :

```
fonction38lhs[tau_]:=
  Module[{q},
    Dialog[]
    q = Exp[2 tau];
    (SixJSymbolqDef[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}, q] - 
      SixJSymbol[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}]) - 
        ((2*tau)^2 (1/6)) 
          ((1/4) Sum[j[[i]] (j[[i]] + 1), {i, 1, 6}] 
            SixJSymbol[{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}] + 
        Triple[j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, j6])]
```

The behavior of my function doesn't really matter.

When I evaluate `fonction38lhs[0.8]`, my program freezes because of the dialog and I am able to evaluated commands. But if I want to display the value of `tau`, it says it is an unknown variable.

To say it differently, my dialog seems to occur out of the function and not inside. Indeed I can show variables of the notebook outside of the function.

How can I gain access to local variable inside of the function within a dialog session?

Comment: `tau` is not a variable. It is a pattern name.  Its value gets substituted directly, without ever assigning a value to the symbol `tau`.

Comment: When I pass argument to functions I will not be able to check their values inside of the function for example ?

Comment: I suggest you [use the debugger](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119962/12) instead of `Dialog[]`.

Comment: I used Dialog because someone advised me not to use the debugger here : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146953/how-to-write-command-in-debug-mode/146966#146966 
But I feel like mathematica has huge problem with debugging tools...

Comment: Well, I advise you to use the debugger, but do it the way I described it in the answer I linked. Do not try to set any breakpoints using the GUI and you'll be fine.

Comment: ok thank you I'll take a look :)

Comment: Replace that `Dialog[]` with `Assert[False]`, open the debugging tools, check "break on assert", and run the function.  When it stops, you are in a dialog. You can do everything you do in a dialog.  But you will also have a stack window which displays the value of `tau`.

Comment: To be clear, the debugger has a very bad reputation because it really does not work so well with breakpoints.  If you avoid this feature, it is entirely usable and useful.  I use it myself.  [But there are still a few rare problems it can cause.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143257/12)  These are rare enough that I do not often bump into them.

Comment: m_goldberg is correct that the debugger is not very often needed.  Do check his link, and use the functions described there (`Trace`, etc.). I use these much more frequently than the debugger.  My point is that in many cases when you would use `Dialog`, it is more convenient to use the debugger.  You do not often need to use Dialog either ...

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function `tau` is just a number. It does't exist as a variable. To do what you want, you have to introduce an auxiliary variable, say `t`.

Then you can have session like.

[image: session]

Notes:

- `Out[154]`, 8.38906, did not appear until `(Dialog) In[157]` was evaluated.
- The returned value of `t` was used to compute `q`.
- `Out[157]` confirms that `t` was changed at top-level and that  the value returned from `fonction38lhs` is equal to `1 + Exp[2 t]` as it should be.

#### Update

Another possibility for interacting with `tau` goes like this,

[image: session]

If you supply `tau` to `Dialog`, it becomes available in the dialog session as `%`.